# JSON Parse Error on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, intel-xdk

I'm building a app with Intel XDK and Cordova. I'm using Framework7, jQuery and  [localize.js](https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize). When I run the app in the emulator, everything works fine. When I'm trying the app on iOS or Android, I get an error:

```
SytanxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF file /jquery.dev.js 9218
```

I'm using this [jquery version](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js). The localization.js loads a JSON file to get language data. I already validatet that JSON file - it's valide JSON. Well, it works in the emulator, so something strange is going on here. I don't even know how to debug.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the read in JSON is complete that is parsed to this parse function (IE it's not a partial one and needs some sort of buffered read to be completed??) Use console.log if possible to output what the function is receiving.

Comment: @PeterS I just displayed the response the ajax request gave me, and since it gets called several times it worked a few times. In between there is the same error again.

Comment: Is it possible to request the JSON without parsing, that is to say use something like Firefox plugin HttpRequester and just request the URL. Do you get a partial or no response at any time? My point being is that something is truncating the response and hence the error.

Comment: You can use this to debug Android: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging  put a breakpoint on the line above and see if you can follow where the missing data is being dropped. iOS has similar tools for it's dev environment.